# How can I set the order of Zend Form Elements and avoid duplicates

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

In Zend Form, if two elements have the same order, then Zend will totally ignores the second element (instead of displaying it under the first).  Take the following code as an example. Notice that the `City` and `Zip Code` elements have the same order of **4**

```
    $address = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea('address');
    $address->setLabel('Address')
            ->setAttrib('cols', 20)
            ->setAttrib('rows', 2)
            ->setOrder(3)
            ;

    $city = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('city');
    $city->setLabel('City')
         ->setOrder(4)
          ;

    $postal = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('postal');
    $postal->setLabel('Zip Code')
           ->setOrder(4);
```

When this form renders, the `Zip Code` element is nowhere to be found.

If I want to set elements like a buttons dynamically, but tell it to render at the end of the form, how would I do this and not run into the problem of having two elements with the same order?

```
public function addSubmitButton($label = "Submit", $order = null)
{
    $form_name = $this->getName();

    // Convert Label to a lowercase no spaces handle
    $handle = strtolower(str_replace(" ","_",$label));

    $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit($handle);
    $submit->setLabel($label)
           ->setAttrib('id', $form_name . "_" . $handle)
            ;

    /////////    Set the button order to be at the end of the form   /////////
    $submit->setOrder(??????);


    $this->addElement($submit);

}
```

Comment: Why do these elements have the same order? What happens if you give the zip code element order 5?

Comment: If zip code has '5', it works fine... I'm trying to illustrate that when two elements have the same order, the second one is completely ignored. This presents the problem that I have to know the order so I don't accidentally overwrite a previously set element.

Comment: I see, but I never set the order when I use Zend Form, and never had such a problem. Can't you also get the order and see if a certain order number is already set?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really need to use the setOrder() method, I'd work with order numbers 10, 20, 30, 40, ... This way it will be easy to add elements in between already set Elements.

Furthermore, in order to avoid using order-numbers twice, you could use an array, where you store all the numbers from 1 to X. Whenever you set an order number, you set it via a method called getOrderNumberFromArray() which returns the next higher or lower order number still available in the array and unsets this array element.

Alternatively, and maybe even better, you could do getOrder() on the element you want to have before the new element, then increment this order number by X and then loop through the existing form elements and check that the order number doesn't exist yet.

Or you could just use getOrder() on the Element you want to show before and after the new element and make sure you don't use the same order numbers for the new element.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to be late to the question. What I did was extend Zend_Form and override the _sort() method as follows:

```
/**
 * Sort items according to their order
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function _sort()
{
    if ($this->_orderUpdated) {
        $items = array();
        $index = 0;
        foreach ($this->_order as $key => $order) {
            if (null === $order) {
                if (null === ($order = $this->{$key}->getOrder())) {
                    while (array_search($index, $this->_order, true)) {
                        ++$index;
                    }
                    $items[$index][]= $key;
                    ++$index;
                } else {
                    $items[$order][]= $key;
                }
            } else {
                $items[$order][]= $key;
            }
        }
        ksort($items);
        $index = 0;
        foreach($items as $i=>$item){
            foreach($item as $subItem){
                $newItems[$index++]=$subItem;
            }
        }
        $items = array_flip($newItems);
        asort($items);
        $this->_order = $items;
        $this->_orderUpdated = false;
    }
}
```

This differs from the original sort method by putting the items in an array based off of their index and then doing a depth-first traversal to flatten the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$elements = array(); 
$elements[] = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea('address'); 
...... 
$elements[] = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('city'); 
....... 
$elements[] = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit($handle); 
..... 
$this->addElements($elements);
```

All you need to do is add them in the order you want them to show

Comment: But, because of the way I construct the form, adding them in the order I want to show is not plausible. Besides, that totally negates having a "setOrder" method and goes against the idea having an object you can manipulate. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

what i would do is - use a temp array for that - in that keep the element names in desired order (don't mind the keys). Then use foreach like this:

```
foreach(array_values($tempArray) as $order => $name) {
    $form->$name->setOrder($order+1);
}
```

Note the array_values - it will return the values as numbered array ;) Not sure if setOrder(0) works - that's why there is `+1`