# Order Zend_Form Elements

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I'm using Zend Framework 1.12. In one form method I change order of the specific element:

```
$this->getElement('form_book_file')->setOrder(55);
```

And I expect that it will be displayed between elements with orders 50 and 60.

However, when I output form elements with function getElementsAndSubFormsOrdered() element 'form_book_file' is on the old position. I outputted elements order to check that it's correct:

[image]

Should I call any sort() function on the form after I change element's order property?

==================================UPD1

I have found out that form's elements are not re-sorted after you change order element like this in controller:

```
  $this->getElement('form_book_file')->setOrder(55);
```

There is a special flag in Zend_Form class $_orderUpdated which tells if there were any changes in the elements order. The thing is that this flag is not set to true when you call setOrder on the specific element.

Any ideas?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425296/how-can-i-set-the-order-of-zend-form-elements-and-avoid-duplicates

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola thank you for the reply. But I think my problem differs from the one in the post. The thing is that I dynamically change order of the element and now I need somehow to sort form again.